# Set All .jar FIles As Executable

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, java, openjdk

I run Java programs alot on my computer. It runs the latest version of OpenJDK, which is OpenJDK 7. When I try to run a .jar file, it gives me an error saying that the .jar file was not marked as executable. I know how to make a .jar file executable from the terminal, but I am wondering if there is a setting where all .jar files I download will be marked as executable automatically. Does such a setting even exist, or do I just have do deal with manually making every .jar file I download executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could be possible to make all the `.jar` files in the current directory to executable.

```
sudo find . -name "*.jar" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

If you want `chmod` to recursively(it makes the executable even if it present inside subdirectories) make all the `.jar` files as executables then run the below command.

```
sudo find . -name "*.jar" -exec chmod +x -R {} \;
```